# Выборка записей с отсуствующим значением

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется 2 таблицы: users и props. Посмотреть можно [тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36fc76/1). Делаю выборку `ID` из `users`, у которых `property = 31` и `value = 'Y'` Этот запрос выведет **1, 5**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.id AS ID
FROM users U INNER JOIN props UP ON U.id = UP.id_user 
WHERE (U.country = 20) AND (UP.property=31 AND UP.value='Y')
```

Необходимо сделать обратный запрос, т.е. те записи, у которых вообще нет этого `UP.property=31`. Т е должно вывести **3, 6** вместо всех (кроме `country = 30`)

Скрипты схемы и данных:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(15), `country` int)
;

CREATE TABLE props
    (`id` int, `property` int, `id_user` int, `value` varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `name`, `country`)
VALUES
    (1, 'vadim', 20),
    (2, 'petya',   20),
    (3, 'vasya', 20),
    (4, 'serega', 30),
    (5, 'lesha', 20),
    (6, 'vitya', 20)
;

INSERT INTO props
    (`id`, `property`, `id_user`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1, 31, 1, 'Y'),
    (2, 33, 1, 'Y'),
    (3, 36, 1, 'Y'),
    (4, 31, 2, 'N'),
    (5, 33, 2, 'Y'),
    (6, 35, 3, 'N'),
    (7, 32, 3, 'Y'),
    (8, 30, 4, 'Y'),
    (9, 32, 4, 'Y'),
    (10, 31, 5, 'Y'),
    (11, 34, 5, 'Y'),
    (12, 36, 6, 'Y'),
    (13, 35, 6, 'Y')
;
```

Comment: что значит "вообще нет"? не равно 31 или нулл?

Comment: "Вообще нет", значит в таблице props для данного юзера нет property = 31

Comment: Опишите подробней, для чего нужны условия country=20 и value='Y' - в контексте вашей проблемы они кажутся лишними, т.е. вопрос можно задать более лаконично... "Обратный запрос" - не постановка задачи. Перефразируйте, а то в ответах уже пытаемся читать ваши мысли.

Comment: Значение имеет только value. Необходимо добавить еще одно условие к тому, что написал  @Denis :  property = 31 and value<> 'Y'

Comment: "кроме country=30" - неверно. Помимо значений 20 и 30 могут быть другие значения country, переформулируйте вопрос в более правильном виде. Конечно, в тексте вопроса, а не в комментариях. Чтобы другие пользователи по вашему вопросу смогли найти ответ на их вопрос.

Comment: @vgedich я, например, всё равно не понял

Comment: @Denis  Ваш запрос ищет записи в props, у которых нет property = 31.. А как сделать, чтобы искало те, у которых property = 31 and value <> 'Y', а также записи,  у которых нет property = 31

Comment: @vgedich объедините 2 запроса через UNION, например. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id as id
FROM users u
WHERE u.country = 20
      AND u.id NOT IN (SELECT p.id_user
                       FROM props p
                       WHERE p.property = '31')
```

В подзапросе мы получим всех юзеров, у которых есть `property = '31'`, в итоге их отсеиваем.

---

На основе дополнения ТС из комментов:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id as id
FROM users u
WHERE u.country = 20
      AND u.id NOT IN (SELECT p.id_user
                       FROM props p
                       WHERE p.property = '31')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT U.id AS ID
FROM users U INNER JOIN props UP ON U.id = UP.id_user 
WHERE (U.country = 20) AND (UP.property=31 AND UP.value<>'Y')
```

Выбираем записи у которых в props нет `property = 31`, объединяем с запросом, у которого в props `property = 31 and value <> 'Y'`

Comment: В вашем запросе выводиться также юзер 2 у которого в таблице props есть свойство 31. А по условию все без 31.

Comment: @AndriiKulyk обратите внимание на строку _На основе дополнения ТС из комментов_, на наличие 2 запросов в моём ответе и прочитайте, пожалуйста, комменты к вопросу.

Comment: Да вот еще раз посмотрел там было утвержение -  
"Вообще нет", значит в таблице props для данного юзера нет property = 31 - у 2го юзера есть свойство 31.

Comment: @AndriiKulyk я посоветую всё же _внимательней_ прочитать комментарии и посмотреть правку моего ответа. Дальнейший спор бессмысленнен, вы не поняли, что хотел автор.

Answer (score 2):

Так выводит 3 и 6:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.id
FROM users U 
WHERE (U.country = 20) 
AND 31 not in (SELECT P.property FROM props P WHERE P.id_user = U.id);
```

В подзапросе мы выбираем все `property` для текущего юзера и если у него нет свойства 31 тогда и отбираем его.